# Finder Bus Error 10/Finder freezes and doesn't open a new window

Tags: macos, finder, crash, performance, logs

About a month ago, my MacBook Pro from 2008 running OSX Lion 10.7.5 booted up incredibly slowly. I reset the PRAM and removed and put back the battery and that issue resolved itself but after that incident, my Finder has not successfully opened a new window when I click it from the dock or when I click on a folder on the desktop. What happens is that the cursor does the rainbow-spinning wheel thing for about two minutes and then stops without opening a new window. The same goes for if I click anywhere in my desktop when Finder is the active application. The only ways I have been able to access my files have been through a spotlight search and through another account on the same computer where Finder does work.

I have thoroughly searched mac support forums for the last month and have found people with similar issues who have resolved them through these things I have tried but have not helped:
*deleting the finder .plist file in Terminal
*doing a "killall" for Finder in Terminal and Activity Monitor and starting it back up
*running Repair Preferences and a Verify/Repair Disk in Disk Utility, which made some repairs but did not change or help my Finder issue

I don't have Time Machine set up and I'd rather not go through the trouble of unlocking all my files on the new Admin User account I set up if I don't have to; not to mention re-setting up/tweaking Firefox to the way I have it now.

Here is a system log.  I've substituted "me" for my computer's name and "myname" for my name that is also on the computer.

```
Jan 27 21:06:19 me com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[124] (com.apple.Finder[237]): Job appears to have crashed: Bus error: 10
Jan 27 21:06:19 me ReportCrash[259]: Saved crash report for Finder[237] version 10.7.5 (10.7.5) to /Users/myname/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2014-01-27-210619_me.crash
Jan 27 21:06:19 me ReportCrash[259]: Removing excessive log: file://localhost/Users/myname/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2013-12-29-160247_me.crash
```

Comment: Why not set up Time Machine, let it backup and then install 10.7.5 again from the Mac App Store?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeated crashes of Photos app due to signal: Bus error: 10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299847/repeated-crashes-of-photos-app-due-to-signal-bus-error-10)

Comment: @kenorb - As this is 3 years old and the suspected dupe is as of today - isn't it a bit roundabout?

Comment: @Allan The age doesn't matter. This hasn't got any answers. See: [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/55075)