# Repeated crashes of Photos app due to signal: Bus error: 10

Tags: crash, photos.app, high-sierra

I'm not sure if I'm the only one but every time I click 'Edit' on a photo that has already been edited by the previous version of Photos, it just crashes. This is frustrating because I did a lot of retouch edits in my library and now I can't edit any of those photos.

I'm using referenced-based library (do not make copy of imported photos) so maybe it happens only on those kind of libraries.

The only sign I see for the crash are two lines in the `system.log`:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Photos.1028[1637]): Service exited due to signal: Bus error: 10 sent by exc handler[0]
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Host-level exception raised: pid = 1637, thread = 0x8d043, exception type = 0xd, codes = { 8589934602 }, states = { 0 }
No reports are being generated
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: @kenorb Thanks. I couldn't find anything in the User Reports or the stream. But in the System Reports I can see all the reports from the photos app. However, those are long to paste here. Seems like there is some recursion going on there..

Comment: I think you should also report this crash at https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @kenorb I'm sorry for confusing you before but the reports I saw were old. I cleared all and ran several crashes but no report is being generated in System/User.

Comment: If it crashed, it should be logged. Double check in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`. This may help: [Where can I find my crash logs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/26480/22781). E.g. you can run `log stream` or `tail -f /var/log/system.log` and monitor for any extra information about your crash while it crashes.

Comment: @kenorb The only sign I see for the crash are two lines in the system.log:
`com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Photos.1028[1637]): Service exited due to signal: Bus error: 10 sent by exc handler[0]
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Host-level exception raised: pid = 1637, thread = 0x8d043, exception type = 0xd, codes = { 8589934602 }, states = { 0 }`
No reports are being generated.

Answer (score 1):

In general *[Bus error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) 10* means that the program has died due to an unhandled `SIGBUS` signal.

The fault can related to some sort of hardware error (possibly a USB device as per [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7145240)) as it is raised by hardware notifying an operating system about the memory access that the CPU cannot physically address (an invalid address for the [address bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bus)).

So if you're using any external device (such as smart phone) to import your photos, try to replace the cable or reboot the device it-self and re-try again. Otherwise please check your SSD/HDD for any hardware faults.

Also to make sure your Mac is healthy, perform the following tests:

- Use [coconutBattery](http://coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) app to check your current battery health.
- Run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).